# inserting a moment into g+ from python

Tags: python, google-plus

My question is very similar to [moment.insert from python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261974/moment-insert-from-python-code) but Fausto has already managed to get further than me so I'm unable to apply that answer at this time.

My code looks like this, and my question is "how do I post to my g+ profile"

```
user = 'awarner@######.com'
key = open(keyFile, 'r').read()
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    '#########@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    key,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
    sub=user)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build(serviceName='plus', version='v1', http=http)

# Not really required here but these calls demonstrate that we are authenticated
searchResults = service.people().search(query='AlistairWarner').execute()
listMoments = service.moments().list(userId='me', collection='vault').execute()

moment = { "type" : "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
            "target" : {
                    "id" : "target-id-1",
                    "type" : "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                    "name" : "The Google+ Platform",
                    "description" : "A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!",
                    "image" : "https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing.png"
            }
    }

# This call fails with a "401 Unauthorized" error
insertResults = service.moments().insert(userId='me', collection='vault', body=moment).execute()
```

Just for the record I have confirmed that I have correctly delegated domain-wide authority to my service account for the necessary scopes - although I don't believe that this is really an authorization issue *per se* because the list call is working. I have also confirmed that my "App" appears on my g+ profile under Apps as mentioned by Prisoner in response to Fausto's question (referenced above).

Looking at the [API reference page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) it does warn that you will get the 401 error that I am seeing. It, and other posts here on StackOverflow (I'd give the ref but not allowed to), say that you need to add the data-requestvisibleactions (again, can't give ref) attribute but I am struggling to see the relevance of the Sign-In Button that they describe attaching it to in my code - which has no UI, I just run it from the command line. So, requestvisibleactions does seem to be the best candidate, I just don't know how to translate that into something that I can use here.

Does anyone have a clue how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this as part of your OAuth request credentials. So it might look something like

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
  '#########@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  key,
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
  requestvisibleactions='http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
  sub=user)
```

Comment: Tried that - no difference, still get 401 "Unauthorized"